# Vista 64-bits development tools

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit

Well, okay. There's Visual Studio 2008 and Embarcadero Delphi/Studio that are both able to create 64-bits .NET applications for Vista. And of course a lot of 32-bits applications will run on 64-bits Vista. If not, it's always possible to install VMWare to create a virtual 32-bits Windows XP system to run 32-bits applications. So, plenty of options.

But what I would like to see is a list of true 64-bits applications for Windows Vista and better. So if you know any useful 64-bits product, please share! (Especially compilers that generate **native** 64-bits code.)

---

Tools would basically be anything that would make development a bit easier. Thus, debugging tools, image processing tools to create icons and bitmaps, hex editors to check the contents of binary files, XML editors to change XML files, etc. The tools from [SysInternals](http://sysinternals.com), for example, seem to provide 64-bits versions or even support 64-bits systems natively. But how about all those other editors, viewers, browsers and other tools that we developers like to use? A 64-bits version of the Norton Commander/Midnight Commander or other file managers would be nice too.
And with compilers, how about COBOL/ForTran/ADA/SmallTalk/Lisp/Whatever compiler/languages for Vista? I would just like to see a complete list of anything useful for 64-bits development.

Comment: Exactly what are you looking for? Tools that produce 64-bit native images? For which 64-bit platform? Ok if they produce bytecode or IL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some examples of open source tools that have been ported to Win64:

- Languages/Compilers/VMs:

  - LUA
  - LuaJIT (beta)
  - Python
  - Factor
  - OCAML  (generates native 64bits code)
  - MinGW 64 (GCC)
  - Clozure Common Lisp (thru MinGW 64)
  - Sun Hotspot JVM (JAVA)
- Other Useful tools:

  - Notepad 2
  - Firefox/XulRunner/SpiderMonkey

Notes:

- With the advance of MinGW 64, we can hope that more and more projects will support Win64 soon (I vote for GTK/Gimp, Squeak VM, Erlang HIPE and CLISP).
- Soon, there should be the javascript V8 engine from Google.
- There is no port of any one of Norton/Midnight/Total Commander to 64 bits.

Answer (score 4):

Both Visual C++ 9 (2008) and gcc know to create 64 bit native code.

Comment: Any more tools and compilers?

Comment: "Tools" is a very generic term. Could you please be more specific?

As for compilers... I am not sure about other compilers, so I prefer to remain silent from now on on this subject :).

Comment: Done. Changed the question. "Tools" is indeed meant to be as generic as possible. Anything that would be useful for 64-bits development.

Answer (score 2):

arguably not a lang, but mySQL is available as Win64

Answer (score 1):

What about the following:

Minefield (Firefox) - this is a beta version of Firefox

SQL Server 2005

TortoiseSvn - works well, and you can still use it if other team-members
are running the 32-bit version

SmartFTP

Paint.NET

Answer (score 1):

I hope you'll take a look at Hamilton C shell 2009 (link is in my profile), which recreates the UNIX C shell and all the usual suspects including grep, fgrep, ls, mv, cp, rm, head, tail, more, diff, strings, tar, etc., all completely from scratch on Windows.  I just released a new version (complete with a brand-new 64-bit build) for Vista this summer which just got a [great review](http://www.4gigs.com/2009/09/19/hamilton-c-shell-2009-the-missing-shell-for-windows/).  There's a free demo version if you'd like to try before buying.  And, yes, I am a real person and I really will answer any questions you might have.

Comment: The C shell looks good but I have my history in MS-DOS/Windows and never did much with Unix, although I do have some good Unix experiences. Besides, I've learned that when I do need to have a little tool like the ones in this shell, then I just use VS2008 or RAD Studio 2007 to just write a bit of code to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [PowerPad](http://www.quickmediasolutions.com/software/powerpad/download.php). It's a great text-editor that has a 64-bit version.